# Desktop changes automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, virus, desktop

I have a Windows 7 Desktop for which the Desktop icons change automatically on system restart and creates user account folders without creating user accounts.I have tried removing them but find that they reappear on system startup/restart.Library folders and folders such as Downloads point to a different locations.

I have scanned my system with Kaspersky Antivirus but it has not reported any virus or other harmful software.

Is this undetected malware or is there a much more serious problem going on?

Comment: Can you provide a specific before path and after path as an example?

Comment: Are you in a active directory domain. It could be group policies are resetting your desktop